# .NET Regex that excludes an optional suffix from the match

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need to match a product in the below strings. They have a required prefix `GENERAL REQUIREMENTS` and an *optional* suffix `APPLICATIONS`. I need to exclude the prefix (that much I got working) and the suffix (still getting included despite my best efforts).

```
GENERAL REQUIREMENTS FOR VALVE APPLICATIONS // should match "VALVE"
GENERAL REQUIREMENTS OF FOO BAR APPLICATIONS // should match "FOO BAR"
GENERAL REQUIREMENTS FOR DURDLES // should match "DURDLES"
```

My current regex:

```
(?<=GENERAL REQUIREMENTS FOR |OF ).*(?=APPLICATIONS)?
```

Is including `APPLICATIONS` in the match for the first two.

**Edit:** Is there a way to exclude optional prefix and suffix as well, while requiring that at least one be present? This is what my unit test looks like; I'm building it up as we discover more special cases (the assert uses FluentAssertions):

```
    [Theory]
    [InlineData("", "")]
    [InlineData("NO CATEGORY HERE", "")]
    [InlineData("GENERAL REQUIREMENTS FOR VALVE APPLICATIONS", "VALVE")]
    [InlineData("GENERAL VALVE REQUIREMENTS", "VALVE")]
    [InlineData("VALVE REQUIREMENTS", "VALVE")]
    [InlineData("INSTALLATION OF VALVES", "VALVES")]
    public void ExtractProductCategoryFromArticle_ReturnsExpectedCategory(string articleText, string expectedCategory)
    {
        string actualCategory = StringUtilities.ExtractProductCategoryFromArticle(articleText);
        actualCategory.Should().Be(expectedCategory);
    }
```

I ended up solving the problem without regular expressions, using a string.StartsWith() and string.EndsWith() check to make sure at least one prefix or suffix is present, then replacing those same words with empty string in the result and trimming it.

Comment: Why Regex. Do this. `var teststring = "GENERAL REQUIREMENTS FOR VALVE APPLICATIONS";`. Then `teststring = teststring.Replace("GENERAL REQUIREMENTS","").Replace("APPLICATIONS","").Replace("For","").Replace("OF","");`. You'll get `VALVE`

Comment: This is the starting point for a regex that will likely grow to include many words; I'd rather have a single regex than a bunch of string.Replace() statements (yes, I know they're faster).

Comment: Ok. The answer by @Wiktor seems good enough :)

Comment: @Nobody after adding some more complexity to the requirements, I ended up going with good old string replace. The problem began to look more and more like trimming certain words from before and after, so that's what I did. Learned a lot about regex today, though!

Comment: Truth to be told. I suggested `Replace` in the first place because i know nothing about `Regex` :D I usually end up making extension methods using replace and all for strings

Comment: Let's discuss the special cases. Please let know either via comment, or please update the question.

Comment: I will check tomorrow in the morning, I need some sleep now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may keep your regex structure, but remove `?` at the end and make the `.*` lazy:

```
(?<=GENERAL REQUIREMENTS FOR |OF ).*?(?=APPLICATIONS|$)
                                    ^               ^^
```

The `$` will make it match also at the end of the string (`.*?` will match up to the end of string) and `.*?` will match as few chars as possible.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3DGENERAL%20REQUIREMENTS%20FOR%20%7COF%20%29.*%3F%28%3F%3DAPPLICATIONS%7C%5Cr%3F%24%29&i=GENERAL%20REQUIREMENTS%20FOR%20VALVE%20APPLICATIONS%0D%0A%20%2F%2F%20should%20match%20%22VALVE%22%0D%0AGENERAL%20REQUIREMENTS%20OF%20FOO%20BAR%20APPLICATIONS%0D%0A%20%2F%2F%20should%20match%20%22FOO%20BAR%22%0D%0AGENERAL%20REQUIREMENTS%20FOR%20DURDLES%0D%0A%20%2F%2F%20should%20match%20%22DURDLES%22&o=m).

However, you may also capture the part you need to get rid of the costly lookbehind:

```
(?:GENERAL REQUIREMENTS FOR|OF)\s*(.*?)(?:APPLICATIONS|$)
```

See [another regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3AGENERAL%20REQUIREMENTS%20FOR%7COF%29%5Cs*%28.*%3F%29%28%3F%3AAPPLICATIONS%7C%5Cr%3F%24%29&i=GENERAL%20REQUIREMENTS%20FOR%20VALVE%20APPLICATIONS%0D%0A%20%2F%2F%20should%20match%20%22VALVE%22%0D%0AGENERAL%20REQUIREMENTS%20OF%20FOO%20BAR%20APPLICATIONS%0D%0A%20%2F%2F%20should%20match%20%22FOO%20BAR%22%0D%0AGENERAL%20REQUIREMENTS%20FOR%20DURDLES%0D%0A%20%2F%2F%20should%20match%20%22DURDLES%22&o=m)

Example usage:

```
var res = Regex.Matches(s, @"(?:GENERAL REQUIREMENTS FOR|OF)\s*(.*?)(?:APPLICATIONS|$)")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value)
    .ToList();
```

[image]